# Message shown before On page re- load , not working after page re-load

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax response code like the follows

```
function click_delete_reply(){
    if ((ajMsgDel.readyState == 4) && (ajMsgDel.status == 200)) {
        var restxt = ajMsgDel.responseText;
        if (restxt == "success") {
            location.reload();
            display_messagesuccess(
                "Message Delete has been successfully performed!");
        }
    }
}
```

I need to reload the page after ajax response success and then I need write a message in a 'div'. But here After message shown then only it performs the page load. What can I do to overcome this? Please help me!

Comment: You cannot write message after page is reloaded since your js isnot running anymore after reload();

Comment: So How can I solve this issue buddy?? @doniyor

Comment: Why dont you first show the message and then reload? The order doesnot make difference here since your ajax job was successful anyways.

Comment: I need the message should be shown after the job is done, in page reload in ajax I am updating certain values which is coming from DB. Thats why I need message after reload. Any method?? @doniyor

Answer (score 1):

Ok, fine, then try something likw this.

Before reload, attach some param to your url. With this, you can know in serverside if it was a reload from your ajax and return one more msg back like "reloaded". Then you do this:

```
$(function(){
   //if the param in url is called "reloaded"
   // then show message

});
```

$(function(){}); is the same as "DOM is ready"

Sorry i am in the bus, couldnot write much. Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do here is

```
1. Instead of Ajax Call give a server request and do the server side processing. 
a) If the job is done successfully just send the message as the request parameter. Read that message and display where ever you want. 
b) If the job fails then just return the values you need as response back to the page and display them where they should be.
```

Since a script is loaded everytime a page is loaded there is no way you can display a message by script message after the page is reloaded. You can either display the message and then reload page. or go with the way i mentioned above.

Comment: That cant be done buddy, because it works in a different funda!! How can I overcome this? Any ideas??

Comment: you can pass a param like `?msg=This-is-message`. and then display this message on the UI